# Black and white science fiction movie with aliens and dome

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, black-and-white

I saw this science fiction a long time ago.  I recall a light plane having to land.  The pilot and a woman struggling to survive in a town that has had some kind of dome placed over it.  I recall scenes where they are hiding out in a cabin in the woods near the edge of the dome, and he is trying to tunnel under it.  I also recall some kind of "feeding centers" in town and people being abducted slowly by the aliens.  Strike any bells?

Comment: I'm not certain it was black and white. I too, remember this movie, and it's been driving me crazy. (Even though, I doubt it's available on video even if I know the name.) I remember: -The car going down the road at night, and seeing head lights. They think that it's another car, but it's actually their own lights reflecting off the "dome", or invisible wall. -I also remember the "feeding centers". But I'm having a really hard time remembering what the aliens looked like, if we ever saw them. Honestly, I can't remember much more. I find it interesting that we both remember the same two creepy

Comment: For what it's worth, I remember it too. I remember the zombie like population and the feeding centers, which were kind of blobby. It was probably a metaphor for communism.

Comment: Like so many others, The Dome has reminded me of an old sifi show or movie about a small Midwest town under an invisible dome. From what I can remember, it’s more like a fish bowl. You know, like a small child with frogs or turtles in an aquarium. At one point several men pile into a 50’s pick-up and try to leave town. They hit the barrier and the truck bursts into flames. You see a shadow coming across and the truck is lifted up and away. In another part the people are in town, one is a lady with a baby. The baby is crying loudly. The shadow comes across again, lifting the lady and baby away.

Comment: Not sure if I'm helping here, but [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15808/alien-invasion-and-a-town-surrounded-by-an-invisible-barrier) seems to talk about the same movie. Noticed the similarities because of the "invisible barrier" and the "car seeing reflection" scene.

Answer (score 3):

Might it be *[The Bubble](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060396/)* (1966) (AKA *Fantastic Invasion of Planet Earth*)?

Here is a plot description from an [IMDb user review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060396/reviews):

> A small prop plane flying through a rainstorm must land because one of the two passengers is about to have a baby.
>
> When the young couple and the pilot put down in the small American town, they find all the townspeople are in a near-catatonic state. The three explore and find fallen Roman columns. They try to drive out of the town but run into an invisible barrier surrounding it. Is there anything left alive on the outside, or is this the last town on Earth? The pilot is plucked from above, is a giant alien collecting specimens? The couple find a small factory producing alien food for the townspeople. Will the baby survive if the food source is destroyed? Is there a limit to the barrier, and can it be surmounted?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember "feeding centers", but the dome and the light plane and the aliens bring to mind **The Slime People** (1963).  Does [this trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfHJZxVK00g) look familiar?

From the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Slime_People):

> The film concerns a race of subterranean reptile-men (dubbed "slime
>   people" due to their slime-covered skin) who create a wall of
>   "solidified fog" around Los Angeles and proceed to invade the city.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it.  The dome was maybe reflective.  I think I recall the main characters at one point trying to drive out of the town and thinking they are about to drive head on into a another vehicle, but come to a screeching halt and realize if was the reflection of their vehicle's lights int he mirrored surface.

Comment: I think at the end of the movie the dome or glass is unexpectedly lifted and the main characters finally manage to leave the town.